# Why JSONObject elements are not parsing when serializing a POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a POJO that I am using as a `ResponseEntity` in `Spring Boot` as part of a Global Exception Handler. It effectively returns a response to the user when an exception is encountered in this application.

[image: POJO Structure before serializing]

When the object gets serialized to JSON, the two `JSONObject` properties (`errors` and `validationErrors`) get messed up:

```json
{
    "instance": "VALIDATION",
    "message": "One or more fields failed validation",
    "status": null,
    "errors": {
        "empty": false
    },
    "hasErrors": true,
    "hasValidationErrors": true
}
```

Note that the `errors` property gets changed to `errors: {"empty": false }`, and the `validationErrors` property disappears completely.

What am I missing here? I have tried using a number of methods to serialize the object:

- pojo.toString()
- objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
- passing response object directly to new ResponseEntity()

All methods result in the same output.

Comment: Don't use multiple JSON libraries. Jackson doesn't know how to serialize a `org.json.JSONObject` as raw JSON. It considers it a pojo and its only "property" is the `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - what should I use to get the needed functionality?

Comment: Jackson's corresponding type for a generic JSON object is `ObjectNode`. Use that type for your fields (assuming they're too complex to be POJOs themselves). Alternatively, you can write a custom `JsonSerializer` for your `ExceptionResponse` class (or for `JSONObject` itself).